# How can I start using web3 version 1.x

Tags: web3js

in the web3 version 1.x docs: 
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/getting-started.html
it says to install web 3 using

```
> npm install web3
```

but this installs version 0.2x.00.

so what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To view all versions of an npm package, enter `npm view web3 versions`. It'll list an array of all available version. To install a specific one, type `npm install web3@versionNumber`.

Answer (score 2):

run

```
sudo npm install -g web3@1.0
```

which will list all available versions:
Valid install targets:

```
npm ERR! 1.0.0-beta2, 1.0.0-beta1, 1.0.0-beta.28, 1.0.0-beta.27, 1.0.0-beta.26, 1.0.0-beta.25, 1.0.0-beta.24, 1.0.0-beta.23, 1.0.0-beta.22, 1.0.0-beta.21, 1.0.0-beta.20, 1.0.0-beta.19, 1.0.0-beta.18, 1.0.0-beta.17, 1.0.0-beta.16, 1.0.0-beta.15, 1.0.0-beta.14, 1.0.0-beta.13, 1.0.0-beta.12, 1.0.0-beta.11, 1.0.0-beta.10, 1.0.0-beta.9, 1.0.0-beta.7, 1.0.0-beta.6, 1.0.0-beta.5, 1.0.0-beta.4, 1.0.0-beta.3, 1.0.0-beta.2, 1.0.0-beta.1, 0.20.4, 0.20.3, 0.20.2, 0.20.1, 0.20.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.0, 0.18.4, 0.18.2, 0.18.1, 0.18.0, 0.17.0-beta, 0.17.0-alpha, 0.16.0, 0.15.3, 0.15.2, 0.15.1, 0.15.0, 0.14.1, 0.14.0, 0.13.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.1, 0.12.0, 0.11.0, 0.10.0, 0.9.2, 0.9.1, 0.9.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.0, 0.6.0, 0.5.0, 0.4.3, 0.4.2, 0.4.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.6, 0.3.4, 0.3.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.2.8, 0.2.7, 0.2.6, 0.2.5
```

choose the most updated. or other if you have any reference.
then u can run

```
sudo npm install web3@1.0.0-beta.28
```